# ng-if or ng-show/hide, which one to use

Tags: angularjs

i know that:

```
The ng-if directive removes the content from the page and ng-show/ng-hide 
uses the CSS display property to hide content.
```

but what i want to understand is: given i am dealing with a simple form - which one should i use? and given that i am dealing with large data / tables - which one should i use?

given: ng-required needs same condition as ng-show, else the form validation suffers and ng-if has no such issue, is it best to use ng-if??

Comment: At ng-conf they said to use ng-if.

Comment: It's best to never say always in programming. Use what suits your needs best at the moment.

Comment: I would guess there are performance ramifications for adding and removing elements from the DOM vs just adding a class to those elements. Also animations may be easier (sometimes) for ng-hide/show versus ng-if. I'm guessing it all comes down to use case as well as what reads more easily!

Comment: My motto is, if the condition is fixed after rendering to use ng-if, and if the condition is changing to use ng-show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-if... you wont have to do addition manipulation to get the validation messages for ng-hide element...

if you use ng-hide then hidden messages would still be validated